# ggplot cowplot ensuring y axes are identical when arranging plots with log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, cowplot

I want to create a combination plot using `plot_grid` from the `cowplot` package.
The two plots that I want to combine use a log scale. Of the data plotted, some is negative, which gets dropped.

I can quite easily produce a decent result using `facet_wrap` that looks like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
tibble(x = rnorm(100), 
       y = rnorm(100),
       type = "A") %>% 
  bind_rows(tibble(x = rnorm(100, mean = 10), 
                   y = rnorm(100, mean = 10),
                   type = "B")) %>% 
  
  ggplot(aes(y = y, x = x)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_wrap(~type)
```

[image]

But in my particular situation, I can't use `facet_wrap` because I want to give the panels A and B different x-axis labels and want to change the number format slightly (e.g. adding a $ sign to the axis ticks of panel A and a % sign to panel B).

Therefore I use plot_grid:

```r
tibble(x = rnorm(100), 
       y = rnorm(100),
       type = "A") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = y, x = x)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10() -> a



tibble(x = rnorm(100, mean = 10), 
       y = rnorm(100, mean = 10),
       type = "B") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = y, x = x)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_y_log10() -> b

cowplot::plot_grid(a,b)
```

[image]

Now the problem is that the axis is completely distorted (this would be equal to `scales = "free_y"` in `facet_wrap`)

So therefore I attempt to set the limits/ranges for both plots manually by choosing the min and max from both plots:

```r
lims <- c(min(layer_scales(a)$y$range$range, layer_scales(b)$y$range$range),
          max(layer_scales(a)$y$range$range, layer_scales(b)$y$range$range))


cowplot::plot_grid(a + ylim(lims),b + ylim(lims))
```

But now the result is this:

[image]

**So essentially I want to replicate the `scales="fixed"` in `facet_wrap` using `plot_grid`**
Any ideas?

many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you provide y axis limits in log10 scale as returned by `layer_scales`. You need to convert it to actual values.

```
lims = 10^c(min(layer_scales(a)$y$range$range, layer_scales(b)$y$range$range),
            max(layer_scales(a)$y$range$range, layer_scales(b)$y$range$range))
```

Alternatively, you can compute the range of the actual data.

Comment: That's excellent! I had played around with `exp` and other stuff but never really managed to get there. So many thanks for this quick reply!